# is PyMongo / MongoDB insert_many transactional?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

For speed of upload, I have a multiprocessing Python program that splits a CSV into many parts, and uploads each in a different process.  Also for speed, I'm putting 3000 inserts together into each insert_many.

The trick is that I have some bad data in some rows, and I haven't yet figured out where it is.  So what I did was a Try/Except around the insert_many, then I try to insert again the 3000 documents, but one at a time, inside another Try/Except.  Then I can do a pprint.pprint on just the rows that have errors.

However, I'm wondering if when the update of 3000 documents fails because of an error, in for example the 1000th row, does the entire 3000 fail?  Or do the first 999 rows get stored and the rest fail?  Or do the 2999 rows get stored, and only the one bad-data row fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do inserts via a bulk write, you can set the ordered option.

When ordered is true, inserts stop at the first error.

When ordered is false, inserts continue past each document that failed for any reason.

In either case, bulk writes are not transactional in the sense that a failure doesn't remove any previously performed writes (inserts or otherwise).

If you would like a transaction, MongoDB provides those as an explicit feature.

Comment: Thanks!  But no way to rollback the first ones?

Comment: Also, there is now way to identify which of the 3000 rows failed?  Is there a rowNumber that can be returned?

Comment: If you want to have a transaction, use transactions. Bulk write error returns information about the failure thought this isn't necessarily extensively documented in driver documentation.